# How to retrieve a value into an array using c++?

Tags: c++, arrays, sockets, client, java-server

I tried to search into an array a value coming from a server java.The server send data after a click on a button and this value is received into `estratto` which is a char array. 
I need to find `estratto` into the string array `numeri` or into the string variable `number`.

How can I do this?

Here's my code:

```
char estratto[2048];
int pos=-1;
char message[2048] = "";
//-- some code

while(recv(sock, buff, sizeof(buff),0) > 0){
            strcat(message,buff); // received message form client
        }

//-- some code

//-- divided message into a string array
istringstream iss(message);
    string token;
    string numeri[15];
    int i=0,j=0,e=0;

    while (std::getline(iss, token, ','))
    {
        numeri[i]= token.c_str();
        i++;
    }



//-- the part that has problems
    string number(message);
    while(recv(sock, estratto, sizeof(estratto),0)>0){          
                for(i=0; i<15; i++){
                    pos=number.find(estratto);
                    if(pos>0)
                        cout<<"TROVATO!"<<endl; 

                    if(strcmp(numeri[i].c_str(),estratto)==0){
                        trovati_cartella[i]=1;
                        cout<<"TROVATO!"<<endl;         
                    }
                }
            }
```

The **cout <<"Trovato!" << endl;** doesn't work if I try to change some parts of this code. Someone can help me to find the solution?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? Don't you get any output? The wrong output? Build errors? Please elaborate and give us details. Also include the types of all variables involved, and possibly how they are initialized.

Comment: Oh and by the way, you do know that C-style strings (which I suppose you receive from the server) should be terminated by the `'\0'` character? Is the data you receive terminated that way?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I don't see the output `cout <<"Trovato!" << endl;`

Comment: "The code works but I don't see any correct results" is nonsense. If you so not see correct result, code doesn't work.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, it's irrelevant what the server is sending. It is not what she is receiving, that's for sure.

Comment: I have a strong (very very very strong) feeling you asked similar question not so long ago. And you already was told, that you can not expect the whole string sent by the server to be read in a single `recv` call. Until you fix your code to properly handle strings, nothing is going to help you.

Comment: @SilviaB    what about std::cout<<"TROVATO!"<< std::endl;

Comment: @SergeyA I asked a question but its problem is resolved. In this case, I receive a string from the server and I need to find it into an array of string. But the string that I receive is continuosly send to the client because the server send data with an action listener

Comment: @Mourad The string into the array is find but the **cout** doesn't work.. so: I don't see on my screen the string **TROVATO**

Comment: i think it is just a problem of instructions, please re-check the brackets inside your for loop and while loop,

Comment: Assuming that you're using TCP, `recv` can receive anywhere between 1 and `sizeof(estratto)` (2048) bytes, and there is no guarantee that what's in `estratto` is zero-terminated.

Comment: @SilviaB, but you do not seem to understand what was told to you.

Comment: @SilviaB why are you putting the first check [pos=number.find(estratto);
                    if(pos>0)
                        cout<<"TROVATO!"<<endl;] into "for" loop when there is no use of tne indice "i" inside the first "if"

Comment: I don't see string number being initialized anywhere. It is being used here "pos=number.find(estratto)" , but where is it being assigned in the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running into a unsigned vs signed character set issue. You may need to encode and decode the string with the 64 bit encoding standard.

Answer (score -1):

I would modify the code like this:

```
while(recv(sock, estratto, sizeof(estratto),0)>0){          
            for(i=0; i<15; i++){
                pos=number.find(estratto);
                if(pos != std::string::npos)
                    cout<<"TROVATO!"<<endl; 

                if(strstr(numeri[i].c_str(),estratto) != NULL){
                    trovati_cartella[i]=1;
                    cout<<"TROVATO!"<<endl;         
                }
            }
        }
```

Your first check "pos>0" is wrong because if estratto string is contained into number string starting from index 0, your check will not find it.
Your second check by strcmp() function instead would catch estratto string only if it exactly matches numeri[i] string, but not if it is a substring.

Comment: Downvote for failure to address the biggest problem with the code.

Comment: @SergeyA what? Why ?

Comment: @SilviaB, because it has been told to you numrous times, when you call you read like you do, you do not know what will be in the `estratto` variable. There might be only a 1st character by the string sent, followed by rubbish.

Comment: @SilviaB Sergeys point is `recv` will return UP TO `sizeof(estratto)`. You may get less. What you need to do is put the `recv` in a loop, sum `recv`'s return value, and exit the loop when the sum is `sizeof(estratto)`. [Should be something like this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35680497/how-to-change-this-code-to-read-all-data-from-serial-port-in-one-part-not-2-par/35680608#35680608) Ignore the accepted answer. It aborts the connection if it doesn't read the right amount of data. Not what you want to do. Not what they want to do, either.

Comment: @SergeyA You are right, I focused on the two checks which were obviously wrong, assuming that estratto was a well-formed string (ending with \0), something that probably is true by chance (since SilviaB does not talk about crashes) but the code does not check for.